# CraftCMS custom entry query

Tags: twig, craftcms

I'm trying to create a custom query for a page in CraftCMS but it seems that, if I link an entry to a template, entry query is already loaded as the `entry` variable.

I know that I can create a twig extension and link a service class with it, then inside that service, execute a custom query but I would like to hook into the process that initially injects the `entry` query object into the template.

Does anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use EVENT_BEFORE_LOAD_ENTRY?

```
use craft\events\ElementEvent;
use craft\services\Elements;
use yii\base\Event;

Event::on(Elements::class, Elements::EVENT_BEFORE_LOAD_ENTRY, function(ElementEvent $event) {
    // Get the entry query object
    $entryQuery = $event->query;

    // Modify the entry query object as needed
    // ...

    // Assign the modified entry query object back to the event
    $event->query = $entryQuery;
});
```